# Why I do not router in NativeScript Vue using $NavigateTo?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have the follow structure:

```
- /src
- /views
-    Login.vue
-    Home.vue      
- App.vue
```

App.vue

```
<template>
<Page>
    ...
    <Button text="Login" @tap="onButtonTap" class="my-button" />
</Page>
</template>

<script>
...
  methods: {
    onButtonTap:function(){
      this.$navigateTo(Home);
    }
  }
</scritp>
```

One of my modules is `vue-router`:

```
import Vue from 'nativescript-vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(Router);

const router = new Router({
    mode: 'abstract',
    // base: '/',
    // saveScrollPosition: true,
    // transitionOnLoad: true,
    routes: [{
            path: '/login',
            component: () =>
                import ('~/views/Login'),

        },
        {
            path: '/home',
            component: () =>
                import ('~/views/Home'),

        }
    ]
});

export default router;
```

Both using `$navigateTo` and `$router` I receive  a error:

```
JS: [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: $router is not defined"
JS: 
JS: found in
JS: 
JS: ---> <App> at App.vue
JS:        <Frame>
JS:          <Root>
System.err: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
System.err: Calling js method onClick failed
System.err: ReferenceError: $router is not defined
System.err:
```

Comment: last time i've checked, vue-router implementation where incomplete therefore the `Frame` method was the recommended one: https://nativescript.org/blog/getting-your-route-on-with-nativescript-vue-episode-two/

Comment: Can you please give me an example based on my code?

Comment: Sounds like you're not passing the router to the app instance. Post the contents of your `main.js`. I'm not experienced with `nativescript` but on a quick search i see there's a [dedicated package for this](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-vue-router-ns/). Have you tried it?

Comment: I followed this dedicated package `System.err: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Comment: vue router is not implemented, you can directly navigate from one to another component.
for nested navigations You shouf add another `<Frame name="someID" />` and pass as second parameter of `$navigateTo` an object with `frame: someID` setting.
https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/routing/manual-routing/